# Starting VBScript from Access VBA

Tags: vba, vbscript

I'm trying to call a VBScript to launch in 32-bit from with-in an Access VBA function.  I have tried several different variations of Shell, but nothing seems to work, here is my most recent try:

```
Function callVS()
    Dim wsh As Object
    Set wsh = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    Dim errorCode As Integer
    errorCode = wsh.Run("C:\Windows\syswow64\cscript.exe '\\hct431vntgta901\test scripts\machine queries\queryTest.vbs'", 1, True)
    If errorCode <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Error was recieved"
    End If
End Function
```

The script receives an error every time I try to run it, I cannot see what the error is, it just fails to run the script.

I have tried and if I run the following command in CMD it runs the script just fine:

```
C:\Windows\syswow64\cscript.exe "\\hct431vntgta901\test scripts\machine queries\queryTest.vbs"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
wsh.Run("C:\Windows\syswow64\cscript.exe ""\\hct431v ... es\queryTest.vbs""", 1, True)
                                         ^   use escaped double quotes   ^
```

As you have used double quotes from command line and they work, keep them. But to place a double quote inside a string, you need to escape them.

Comment: Thanks so much, I don't know why I didn't think of that thought the single quote would work the same.